# Pysys.py not responding

Tags: python

I have pysys installed. But if i type pysys.py in my command prompt it's not showing any thing.
just it's going to next line without displaying any information..
please help me out

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, it appears to be a framework. You will have to write your testcases yourself and run it using the Testrunner.

Comment: why are you using this and not the standard unittest2, nose or py.test?

Answer (score 0):

The pysys readme does detail the launcher script and it would be worth reading if you have not done so (e.g. see http://sourceforge.net/projects/pysys/files/pysys/0.9.3)

"PySys installs a launcher script 'pysys.py' as part of the installation 
process to facilitate the management and execution of testcases. On unix 
systems the script is installed into the Python binary directory, e.g. 
/usr/local/bin, and is hence on the default user's path. On windows systems 
the script is installed into the Scripts directory of the Python 
installation, e.g. c:\Python27\Scripts\pysys.py, which is not by default on 
the user's path. To run on windows systems the Scripts directory of the 
Python installation should be added to the user's path to allow direct 
execution of the script"